# Is there a way to listen to another class' method execution?

Tags: java, oop

Is it possible to listen to a method execution of an instance or all instances of a class, without modifying their code ?
Something like:

```
someInstance.addMethodExecutionListener('methodName', handler);
SomeClass.addMethodExecutionListener('methodName', handler);
```

It would be for logging purposes...

Comment: So what do you want. Do you need to be notified each time the function `methodName()` starts executing?

Comment: Exactly, and without modifying the Class code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking about is a small subset of what you can do with Aspect Oriented Programming. It's not supported in plain Java and its implementations, but it's the central reason for [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the environment you could use different technologies. Spring provides [Aspects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) that you can bind to certain events (e.g. method execution).

If you are in a Java EE container managed environment you can use [Interceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkeed.html) for EJBs or [SoapHandlers](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) for Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the tooling API, JVMTI (replaces the separate debugging and profiling APIs).

Otherwise, you could rewrite the class files to insert your code before the method code. It's not necessarily easy. ASM is good for bytecode manipulation at a low level, but you might want to use some library (or write your own) or possibly use some "aspect" tool.

Bytecode can easily be rewritten "on disc" before loading, or at runtime using the [instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) and `-javaagent:` on the command line.